# WPF Combobox validationrules

Tags: wpf, combobox, validationrules

I'm trying to launch the validation of my combobox on demands....similar code works perfectly for a textbox but look like the combobox behave completely differently (Text or selectedItem binding) :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="someCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="Model.SomeItem" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validation:SomeValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False">
                </validation:SomeValidationRule >
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>
```

and

```
public class SomeValidationRule : ValidationRule
{

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {

        var userText = value as string;
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userText)?
            new ValidationResult(false, "empty combobox error..") :
            new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

for a textbox I can launch the validation when I want by using the MyTextBox.UpdateSource but I cant find any way to do it with a combobox.

I need to launch the validaiton only on demand in particular situations.

So my question is why someCombo.UpdateSource is not launching my validation?

Thanks

Michel

Comment: Can you show us the `UpdateSource` code that is failing?

Comment: someCombo.UpdateSource()   //Want to manually launch the validation here

Comment: There is no `UpdateSource` method on `ComboBox`.  Can you add your *actual code* that fails to the question?  Are you calling an extension method?  If so, what is the code for that method?

Comment: haa! ok this is a FrameworkElementExtensions (not standard) Just forget about it...  But the question is still valid...how do I launch my validation on demand?

Comment: Posted an answer that works for a quick example based on your code.  Out of curiosity, why do you need to run validation manually?  Why are the standard validation triggers insufficient?  I ask because there may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
var expression = someCombo.GetBindingExpression(Selector.SelectedItemProperty);
if (expression != null)
    expression.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: Thanks it work now...  the only problem is when the application fill the combobox with value based on different thing this launch the validation and I dont want to validate the combobox at this point.  I'm manually running the validation because I want it only on some situation (On lost focus and depending and when the focus is on particular controls.)

Comment: and for some reasons the tooltip with the error is not displayed ...only the red rectangle (i'm not using a particular error template)

Comment: Is it possible to change the default text color and weight for the tooltip? or is there any good simple example for a validation with a custom error template? (like a textblock at the right portion of the control to validate?  (not a wpf popup) Thanks

Comment: These aren't directly related to your original problem, and should be asked as separate questions.